# How to make sliding window a double precision value?

Tags: image, matlab, filtering

MATLAB's `nlfilter` and `imfilter` functions require that the neighborhood have integer values e.g. [63 63].  However, I need to run focal calculations using a window of double precision e.g. [63.615 63.615], or in other words, a 1 acre moving window.  Is it possible to specify a  neighborhood that contains double precision values when making these calculations in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

There is no information below the sampling rate. So moving filters are meant to work at the pixel level. There is the option of upsampling your image before filtering (not without consequences in terms of computational load).

It would give something like (untested):

```
Window=[63.615 63.615];
upsampeled=imresize(I, 100);
f = @(x) YourFunction(x);
I2 = nlfilter(upsampled,Window*100,f);
```

You can then downsample `I2` with `imresize`.

`imresize` will interpolate the values of the pixels using bicubic interpolation. Now there is the more theoretical question of why do you need subpixel processing.

Answer (score 1):

Since ( in my very limited understanding ) `nlfilter` & `imfilter` are block operations. Rescale your input data and in so doing convert it to an int.
  Then you can convert the answer back to float.  However, the data may be too large for `imfilter` and `nlfilter`, well at least it will be slower.